# Squash Commits of a branch after merging in GIT

Tags: git, github, git-commit, squash

Hi I have a branch stable which contains merged commits of other branches. The structure is as follows:

Commit History:

```
Commit 1 - Branch 1 commit 1 ------------- Hash Code 1
Commit 2 - Branch 2 commit 1 ------------- Hash Code 2
Commit 3 - Branch 2 commit 2 ------------- Hash Code 3
Commit 4 - Branch 2 commit 3 ------------- Hash Code 4
Commit 5 - Branch 3 commit 1 ------------- Hash Code 5
```

Branch 1,2,3 are deleted and has been merges with stable. Is there any way that in the commit history I can squash Commit 3 and Commit 4.

The desired result:

```
Commit 1 - Branch 1 commit 1 ------------- Hash Code 1
Commit 2 - Branch 2 commit 1 ------------- Hash Code 2
Commit 5 - Branch 3 commit 1 ------------- Hash Code 5
```

When I do git rebase -i, it gives the noop scrren in rebasing.[image]

Comment: You can do `git rebase -i` to perform an [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

Comment: it gives me noop. I have attached the screenshot also.

Comment: You probably need to correctly specify what you want to rebase onto what. `git rebase --help` to figure that out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do git rebase -i to perform an interactive rebase.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~4
```

change

```
pick  commit 1
pick  commit 2
pick  commit 3
pick  commit 1
```

into this

```
pick  commit 1
s     commit 2
s     commit 3
pick  commit 1
```

save changes and do `git push -f`

Comment: Also, can you tell me that suppose this branch is protected and unnecessary commits are from a pull request. And the branch is deleted and merged. Is there any way I can modify a pull request from which the unnecessary commits will be gone.

Comment: A PR is always from `source` to `target` branch, once the `source` is deleted after merging into `target`, PR becomes non-existent and can't be changed. Any subsequent changes must go into separate PR.

Comment: That is true, but there is a option for restoring the branch where I restored and squashed the extra commits in that branch but it's just I am not getting to work for that PR as I want to squash the unwanted commits into merged branch which is protected.